# Why can't I set a bounty on my question that I've answered myself?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

My reputation is 76 and therefore I'm eligible for setting bounties, I can set a bounty for eligible questions and even on my own previous eligible questions, but when I want to set a bounty on my own question that I've given an answer myself (which is incomplete and I'm looking for other answers), instead of seeing "start a bounty", I see "question eligible for bounty since 6 hours ago". Clicking on that gets me to the help page. I thought that's because I've given an answer myself (which is fairly logical, but not written in the help page). Therefore, I tried copying my answer to the question details and deleting my answer, but after doing so, nothing changed and I still couldn't set a bounty. I thought maybe that's because I can still see my deleted answer! So I undeleted my answer and made it Community Wiki(!!!) thinking that doing so might help. Even after that, I can't set a bounty!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

Comment: But I couldn't set a bounty even when I deleted my answer or even when I made community wiki (then it basically wouldn't be considered my answer)

Comment: @S.Shahsiah The system only cares whether you have written an answer or not. Deleting the answer or making it community wiki has no effect (probably because otherwise everyone would just delete their answer, set the bounty, then undelete it again).